# JNDI Connection Pool Sharing among Apps

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, jndi

I have three war applications(A,B,C) running over Weblogic and each is using same JNDI name for database connections. JNDI has a connection pool having maximum 100 db connections.

Is there a way to share this 100 connection among A,B,and C. lets say A can use maximum 20 connections,
B can use 50 db connections , C can use 30 connection?

There is a work around solution that I can create three JNDI ls say JNDI_A (max 20), JNDI_B and JNDI_C.

Java EE 6

Spring 3.5

weblogic 12c

Comment: what is the reason of being down voted?

Comment: I think you will need to do the workaround - otherwise you can try something like application scoped JDBC http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jdbc/programming.html#1050534 The answer below might work as well... you could set the min capacity to 20 to make sure all of your apps have it

Comment: I want one of Application do not consume all connections so max connections settings will be more meaningfull for me if possible

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to manage it through WebLogic Administration Console. In the console its possible to set an Initial Capacity for each deployment sharing the same DataSource.

Reference: [Dynamically Sizing JDBC Connection Pool in WebLogic Server](http://xmlandmore.blogspot.com/2012/10/dynamically-sizing-jdbc-connection-pool.html)

Comment: I could not find and info how to share connections  among Applications using same JNDI